# Select and Delete entire column in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to select and delete entire column in notepad++?

Assume that there is a log like that in notepad++:

```
Dec 14 14:49:34 :
Dec 14 14:49:35 :
Dec 14 14:49:36 :
Dec 14 14:49:37 :
```

I want to select and delete Just `Dec` in sample log above. All other columns are wanted!

Comment: All rows have 'Dec', from which row you want to delete, or you want to delete from each column, sublime text has option for multiple selection. or you can use Find-Replace

Comment: Good Point! I want to delete entire column "Dec" from all rows

Comment: hold Alt key while mouse select allow you to do column select in notepad++, select interest column and delete afterwards

Comment: Thank you so much.It really worked ! but the problem is number of rows are too many !

Comment: I wonder how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ column mode can be driven from the keyboard. Position the cursor at one corner of the wanted area. Press and hold down the Alt and Shift keys. While holding down the Alt and Shift keys use the arrow keys and the Page-up and Page-down keys to extend the selected rectangular area. Can also use the Home and End keys to extend the area left-right to the beginning or end of the current line.

For this question position the cursor before the "Dec" on the first line of the file. Then, while holding down the Alt and Shift keys, press the right-arrow three times and the Page-down several times until reaching the bottom of the wanted area.

Comment: I just tried this.  I am using Windows 10 on a surface pro 4.  Notepad++ is v7.9.1

Comment: Select and Delete entire column in notepad++ - Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369054/select-and-delete-entire-column-in-notepad)

Comment: @JoeBigler I do not understand your comments. You just tried it and ... what? I am confused by why you would adding a link to the question from one of its answers.

Comment: Alt-Shift-Ctrl-End should take you to the last line of the file but does not :(

Comment: @NetMage Why do you believe that Alt-Shift-Ctrl-End should take you to the last line of the file? It does not on my Notepad++ version 8.5.4. Have you looked in menu => **Settings** => **Shortcut mapper**? Can you please point to the relevant part of the Notepad manual (see menu => **?** => **Notepad++ Online user manual**).

Comment: @AdrianHHH I don't believe it will, I believe it *should*, just like Ctrl-End takes you to the last line without being in column mode and Alt-Shift-PgDn takes you down a page in column mode, other cursor movement should work while staying in column mode when Alt-Shift is held down.

Comment: @NetMage My question was *"Why do you believe [it] should take you to the last line of the file?"*. Again I ask, where in the Notepad++ manual does it say it should? If you are suggesting an enhancement to, or a new feature in, Notepad++ then this is the wrong place. The correct place is on [Github](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues).

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Dec`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  Dec       # literally Dec followed by a space
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Saving File as a text file and then importing the data into Excel (in columns)**

Save the file as a .txt file, by simply going Save As in Notepad.
Then open a blank Excel, go File, Open and then select the .txt file (you may have to change the file type from Excel files to Text Files in the drop down file type selection part).
A Text Import Window will appear in Excel.
Press next to skip Step 1 of 3.
Now in step 2 of 3 you can position the lines where ever you want to create columns. Once happy, press next, and in Step 3 of 3 you can choose to change the column data format if you wish. If want to keep the columns General for the time being, just select finish!