# Notepad ++ : mutiple space

Tags: notepad++, indentation, space, tabular, notepad

I have some data on Notepad on mutiple lines and would like to shift each line by one space " ".

I know that if you select multiple lines and press the "tab" key it will do a tabular for each line but if i do the same operation with "space" all my data is errased.

Is there another way to do it?

Thanks and have a good day :)

Comment: If you change your tab settings to size:1/replace by space, _tab_ and _shift_-_tab_ will insert/remove a single space in the selected area.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59371554/546871 about Notepad++ column  mode.

Comment: I finally found the solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696372/how-to-add-a-space-in-front-of-every-line-in-notepad Thanks :)